# Send dynamic error/failed result message from server

Tags: jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, iis, c#-4.0

I'm using jqgrid in a project. 
And need to know how to return/set error responses on the webserver to allow custom messages.

On my local instance i get the following result.
[image: Local]

But on the deployed site on our webserver the messages get suppressed and replaced with the default message.
[image: Server]

It's worth a mention that i return the error/failed result by setting the response status code to 500, and setting the description to my custom message.
(is there perhaps a better way to do this)

Also ive added/modified the following config values.

```
<customErrors mode="On" />

<system.webServer>
       <httpErrors errorMode="Custom" >
         <remove statusCode="500" />
       </httpErrors>
</system.webServer>
```

Does anyone know what im doing wrong? Or how to get it working :P

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution. Before i updated my web.config to

```
<system.webServer>
       <httpErrors errorMode="Custom" >
         <remove statusCode="500" />
       </httpErrors>
</system.webServer>
```

It was set to (which explains why I experienced the issue in the first place, as I was accessing the site from a remote source)

```
<system.webServer>
       <httpErrors errorMode="DetailedLocalOnly" />
</system.webServer>
```

Changing it to the following

```
<system.webServer>
           <httpErrors errorMode="Detailed" />
</system.webServer>
```

and implementing Muhammad Mudassir suggestion, seemed to do the trick.

Answer (score 1):

Please try this, its better way for [Custom Error Handling](http://www.dotnetcurry.com/ShowArticle.aspx?ID=496)

Comment: I implemented this fix, def a better way of error handling, but i still have the same issue. The status code gets set to 500 and the custom message gets suppressed and replaced by the default error messages

Comment: Seems that your action filter event is not executing, either exception is handled before it (e.g. in Application_error event in global.asax) or another exception is occurring after action filter, please verify.

Comment: It's executing... but i just noticed this line in the global.  public static void RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilterCollection filters)
        {           
            filters.Add(new HandleErrorAttribute());
        }
Will remove it now and see if it somehow overrides the custom error attribute